# Утечка памяти в string.replace

Tags: отладка, память, строки, valgrind

Здравствуйте!
В программе утекает память, запустил через valgrind и никак не могу понять: пишет possible lost в следующей функции на строчке 'return FALSE':

```
ReplaceStr(string& str, const string& from, const string& to)
{
  size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
  if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
    return FALSE;
  str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
  return TRUE;
}
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал. Что делаю не так?

***UPDATE***

```
int CameraType::MakeSourceUrls()
{
  string tmp_str;
  BaseUrlArray *BaseUrls;
  BaseUrls = new BaseUrlArray;

  GetCamTypeFromXml(CamRecParam->ModelName, BaseUrls);

  for (int i = PIPE_MJPEG; i <= PIPE_H264; i++)
    {
      if (BaseUrls->Urls[i].murl.length() < 14)
        {
          sprintf(str, "ERROR: Base URL for camera '%s' for type = %d is not valid\n", CamRecParam->Name.c_str(), i);
          AppendLog(str, "CameraType::MakeSourceUrls", ERROR);
          CamRecParam->UrlVidFormat[i].url = "";
          continue;
        }
      tmp_str = BaseUrls->Urls[i].murl;
      ReplaceStr(tmp_str, "IPADDRESS", CamRecParam->IP);
```

---

---

---

CamRecParam->IP это обычный string

***UPDATE#2***

Для приведенного ниже кода valgrind выдает 0 ошибок. Тип auto заменил на size_type, т.к. у меня нет поддержки auto на данной платформе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool ReplaceStr(string& str, const string& from, const string& to)
{
  std::string::size_type start_pos = str.find(from);
  if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
    return false;
  str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
  return true;
}

int main()
{
    string haystack = "Soft cat, warm cat, little ball of fur";
    string needle = "cat";
    string replacement = "kitty";
    ReplaceStr(haystack, needle, replacement);
    ReplaceStr(haystack, needle, replacement);
    cout << haystack;
    return 0;
}
```

***UPDATE#3***

Полный лог valgrind: http://pastebin.com/UNbR1Jzr

***UPDATE#4***

CamRecParam это просто класс-оболочка свойств камеры (тип, IP-адрес и прочие параметры). Является переменной класса CameraType. Создается при инициализации экземпляра класса CameraType. MakeSourceUrls читает конфигурационный файл xml и заносит полученные параметры камеры в соответствующие поля CamRecParam. Все это выполняется из основного потока программы. У класса CameraType есть также переменная-экземпляр класса Writer, который отвечает за подключение к камере и запись потока на диск. Вот собственно цикл записи этого Writer и выполняется в отдельном потоке. Да, он берет какие-то поля из CamRecParam, но только читает их...

***UPDATE#5***

Модифицировал тестовую программу и получил те же ошибки valgrind! Интрига накаляется...

Программа:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool ReplaceStr(string& str, const string& from, const string& to)
{
  std::string::size_type start_pos = str.find(from);
  if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
    return false;
  str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
  return true;
}

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm;
    struct timeval td;
    char OutString[254];

    t = time(NULL);
    localtime_r(&t, &tm);
    gettimeofday(&td, 0);
    sprintf(OutString + strftime(OutString, 254, "%d.%m.%Y %T", &tm), ".%.3d", (int)     (td.tv_usec / 1000));

    string haystack = "Soft cat, warm cat, little ball of fur";
    string needle = "cat";
    string replacement = "kitty";
    ReplaceStr(haystack, needle, replacement);
    ReplaceStr(haystack, needle, replacement);
    cout << haystack;
    cout << OutString;
    return 0;
}
```

Лог valgrind: http://pastebin.com/HitRG7fJ

Comment: а FALSE и TRUE - это самописные константы или что? Сам тип функции не указан, поэтому, сложно судить. Может быть, FALSE - это define, который создает объект, тогда да, там может быть утечка.

Comment: Да, кое-что подправил.
Сейчас при запуске программы появилась ошибка glib - free - invalid pointer 0x[], но я с этим разберусь.
Построил график /proc/<pid_программы>/status | grep VmRSS с интервалом 5 минут - идет явное увеличение.. с 25084kB при запуске вчера в 19.00 и уже 27528kB сегодня в 14.30...
Причем все definitely lost я убрал, кроме одного, но там один раз при запуске программы и в рабочем цикле не утекает. Остались possible lost, indirect lost ну и still reachable, но последнее видимо из-за того, что я просто убиваю процесс программы и никакой деинициализации не происходит.

Comment: Если уж я не могу разобраться с утечкой в string.replace, то пытаться что-то у себя дальше искать и вовсе бесполезно...

Возвращает bool само собой..

Comment: @Xaruch: Кстати. Попробуйте запустить под valgrind'ом вот такую программу: http://ideone.com/iGf6wR (можно даже убрать `cout`, чтобы не тестировать ввод-вывод), и скажите, всё ли в порядке.
____

@avp: У меня есть большо-о-ое подозрение, что переменные используются потоконебезопасным способом. То есть пока один поток читает переменную, другой её меняет. Код выглядит вменяемо, но valgrind выдаёт ошибки.

Comment: Нет утечек, да и где им там быть.

@Xaruch, думаю, у Вас расстрел памяти. А оно может дать что угодно. А если приложение ещё многопоточное...
_____

Это когда по случайным адресам в памяти пишутся случайные данные. Самый простой и типичный случай
int a[10]; a[10] = 0;
Да, современные компиляторы в курсе таких ошибок и и могут добавить за массивом один пустой элемент, а потом его проверить. Но если писать где-то так
*(a+100000) = 1
то никто не проверит. А вот куда оно запишет - это дело тяжелое.

Comment: @Xaruch: А как насчёт `CamRecParam`? Может ли быть такое, что этот объект используется для записи в другом потоке? В этот самый момент или раньше?

(И попробуйте всё же запустить под valgrind'ом мини-программу!)

Comment: @avp: Хочу отличить, проблема в дырявой стандартной библиотеке (на некоторых платформах возможно), или у программы UB. Ну или я не приметил какого-нибудь слона.

Comment: Сделал Update к вопросу. Собственно для тестовой программы valgrind ошибок не находит. В общем что-то очень тёмное...если даже valgrind не ловит проблему, то как ее вообще найти? Похоже, что нереально.

P.S. Дело в том, что пишется через ffmpeg поток с массива камер.. а цикл чтения/записи фреймов в ffmpeg выполняется в основном потоке. Посему вот этот цикл для каждой камеры выделен в отдельный поток. Циклы записи останавливаются и заново запускаются каждые 5 минут.. собственно видимо в эти моменты и что-то может происходить, хотя сходу не вижу...

Полный лог valgrind в Update#3 к вопросу

Comment: @Xaruch: Я переместил лог на pastebin, а то уж очень много текста.

Comment: @Xaruch: Подождите. расскажите ещё раз про «жизненный цикл» класса `CamRecParam`. Где он создаётся? Какие потоки он создаёт? Из какого потока его использует `CameraType::MakeSourceUrls()`?

Comment: @Xaruch:

> Да, он берет какие-то поля из CamRecParam, но только читает их

Стоп-стоп-стоп. То есть у вас один поток пишет, а другой читает одну и ту же переменную?
___

@Xaruch: Всё плохо.
Вы не имеете права работать с одной и той же переменной в разных потоках. Вы не имеете права предполагать, что моменты времени разные: оптимизатор и кэш процессора могут сдвигать моменты записи.
Добавьте-ка mutex вокруг операций с этой переменной. И никогда не давайте никому указатель на неё, а то он попытается использовать её без mutex'а.
___

@Xaruch: О, уже интереснее. А если убрать sprintf и котят?

Comment: @avp: Это было бы всё равно неправильно, т. к. UB, и оптимизатор имеет право выкинуть этот код полностью. Может, баг?

Comment: @Xaruch: по поводу `localtime_r` подождите анализа @avp.

Comment: @Xaruch, @VladD, часа 3 разбирался в `eglibc-2.11.1/time/*.c`, но так ничего и не нашел.

Не понимаю, как код там может соответствовать стеку valgrind и тестовой программе.

Может, `/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so` у @Xaruch собрана из других исходников?

--

Есть там, правда, одно место, где может возвращается адрес из середины выделенной по malloc памяти (не нравится valgrind-у ???), но по адресам стека у меня это место не вписывается.

Comment: @avp: А у вас valgrind выдаёт ту же диагностику?

Comment: @VladD, OK, я попробовал сейчас на `Linux avp-xub11 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:01 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

    g++ -g xlocaltime.cpp
    valgrind  --leak-check=full  ./a.out
    ...
    ==11366== 
    Soft kitty, warm kitty, little ball of fur11.09.2014  16:21:02.882==11366== 
    ==11366== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==11366==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==11366==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 16 frees, 1,181 bytes allocated
    ==11366== 
    ==11366== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
    ...

Т.е. все нормально.

Comment: @Xaruch, если откровенно, то не знаю. Вечерком еще дома попробую. Вряд ли дело в версии valgrind

(я сейчас гонял  `Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX;`).

У Вас какая система -- `uname -a; g++ --version` ?

(админ!!!

количества комментариев для помощи здорово не хватает).

Comment: @Xaruch: Это может означать, что у вас странная система или странный компилятор. (А какой, кстати?) Или просто устаревшая.

Comment: @Xaruch: Хорошо. И это улучшило результаты valgrind?

Comment: @Xaruch: потому что использование переменных в разных потоках без mutex'а есть UB. Если вы думаете, что программа выполняется построчно, и когда одна строчка гарантировано отработала, другой поток может делать что ему вздумается, то у меня для вас плохие новости. По стандарту имеет право происходить всё, что угодно. [И происходит.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx)

Comment: @Xaruch: Вы всё же не прочитали ссылку. UB имеет право распространяться «назад по времени». Программа, напомню, **не** исполняется построчно, реальная запись в переменную может быть когда угодно или вообще отсутствовать.

Comment: @Xaruch: Стойте. Вы имеете в виду, что эти переменные устанавливаются **один раз** до запуска других потоков и больше никогда не меняются?

Comment: (лимит!!! поэтому удаляю и переношу...)

Проверил тестовую программу на:

Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
valgrind-3.10.0.SVN

тоже никаких утечек и др. ругани.

--

По поводу mutex.

IMHO **здесь** read-only переменные, инициализированные в main thread до основной работы **не влияют**. Для них локи можно и не делать.

Ищите **не thread-safe функции** (библиотечные), которые используются в потоках.

У Вас добавление локов снизило параллелизм и поэтому ошибки в них стали реже.

Comment: @Xaruch, @avp: Совершенно верно, если переменные инициализированы _до_ запуска других потоков, проблем быть не должно, т. к. старт потока есть memory barrier.

Но это в случае, если они потом не меняются, конечно.

Comment: Да, переменные устанавливаются из xml-конфига только при запуске и потом вообще никем не меняются. Потоки запускаются существенно позже и только читают значения этих переменных.
Был у меня один флаг, который менялся в потоке, вот туда я добавил mutex и увидел улучшение. Остальное вроде как не должно влиять...